# Make a javascript 'code snippet' app an installable windows .exe using VS CODE?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code, executable

Ive been learning html, css, js, php, mysql, (touched on node js but ran away from it - too much too soon) for a few months now and would like to make a simple categorized code snippet app as a learning project and to aid my crap memory!

I couldnt find a relevant answer so, hopefully its not a dumb question:

I want to primarily stick with js to get a good coding knowledge base so will make the snippet app using js, and .txt files as the storage. Using VS Code, what would be the best practice/method?

I know I could just make it browser based, but would rather have a little app I can pin to the taskbar, as im coding/self teaching full time atm.

Comment: JavaScript needs an environment to run, you'd need to implement the environment too. I've seen packagers packing the files into a exe, but that's more like a zip file only, the files are temporarily loaded and saved in a folder when running the exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript` natively supported by browsers to develop **Web Apps** *(You cannot run as a native app)*. The `.EXE` files are **executable binary files** of **Windows**. If you want to build **Native Apps** using `HTML, CSS & JS`, You have couple of options.

---

### Electron JS

**Electron JS** is a amazing tool, To build `cross-platform` apps. You can develop your apps using `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS` and build it to any major platforms.

> **VS Code, Invision, MS Teams are built on electron Js**

https://www.electronjs.org/

---

### Use WebView on Native App

If you don't need to access any native function of the system, Then you can go with **WebView**. The web view is a feature to embed a website inside a native app. Most of the languages/frameworks have web-view support *(Eg:- .Net)*.

If you are focusing on windows, Try [.NET Web View](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/11/18/2019-11-18-webwindow-a-cross-platform-webview-for-dotnet-core/)